# div does not animate in jquery. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pesAA/2/). I am trying to make jquery animation but when I click on the link it does not move. Why? I am using jquery transition plugin.

Here is my code

html

```
<header class="header"><a href="#" class="click">Click</a></header>
<section class="contents">
  <section class='home'>
    Hello akdjalskdjalskdjlasklasdjasljdasök
  </section>
</section>
```

css

```
.contents {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.home {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

and js

```
$('.click').click(function () {
      $('.home').transition({x: '+100px'}, function () {
        alert('completed');
      });
    });
```

**Update**

I am using jquery [transition](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) plugin

Comment: What are you trying to animate with `x`?

Comment: @al0neevenings The demos on that plug-in page don't work in my Firefox.

Comment: Your code works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/pesAA/14/

Comment: @MuthuKumaran It doesn't work in Firefox (latest).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Works on Firefox 15.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran How come your Firefox didn't auto-update to 16? Anyway, I'm on 16, and I get `"TypeError: h.setFromString is not a function"` when I click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `animate` and `left` instead of `transition` and `x`:

```
$('.click').click(function () {
    $('.home').animate({left: '+100px'}, function () {
        alert('completed');
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** ​http://jsfiddle.net/pesAA/15/

Comment: Poster is using a plug-in that gives transition()

Comment: If using that plugin, his code should work [http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/pesAA/14](http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/pesAA/14) but my answer also give him another way which can achieve the same result without using unnecessary plugin like that

Answer (score 0):

Taking from `x` that you want to animate along the horizontal axis, then [this should work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/pesAA/8/):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.click').click(function () {
    $('.home').animate({left: '+100px'}, function () {
      alert('completed');
    });
  });
});​
```

Your current code won't work because `x` isn't a thing in this context and `transition` is unnecessary.

Your jsFiddle won't work because it doesn't reference jQuery, but Mootools instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your libraries in jsFiddle. The `transition` framework may be unecessary but if you want it, you have to make sure it is included with in the jsFiddle by adding http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js to the "Add Resources Part". Additionally, it seems to only work with earlier versions of jQuery and not v1.8.2 the latest version. Otherwise your code is fine. Try out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pesAA/16/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.contents {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.home {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header"><span class="click">Click</span></header>
<section class="contents">
  <section class='home'>
    Hello akdjalskdjalskdjlasklasdjasljdasök
  </section>
</section>
</body>
<script> 
$('.click').on('click',function (evt) {
      $('.home').animate({left: '+100px'}, function () {
        alert('completed');
      });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Greetings.